# Using the terms 'theorem 'and 'tautology'

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I would just like some clarification on the use of the terms "theorem" and "tautology".

I have read [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic/Sentential_Logic/Theorems) that a theorem is a "formula for which a zero-premise derivation has been provided".  But [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem) it is a "logical consequence of the axioms".  These definitions seem to be in conflict, as are not axioms just premises (Formulae which are assumed to be true)?

And what about a tautology.  My understanding is that a tautology is the same as the first definition of a theorem.  Or is tautology a semantic thing (i.e. valid) whereas theorem is syntactic (i.e. derivable)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mathematics a *theorem* is a statement that has a proof : **in** a *theory*, i.e. from the *axioms* of the theory.

In a "formal" context, nothing change: a theorem of e.g. [first-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) is a formula that is derivable from the first-order [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms).

---

A [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity#Valid_formula) formula (in the context of *propositional calculus* : a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic))) is a formula that is true in every interpretation.

Logical calculus have more than one "modes of presentation" :

> Hilbert-style : (logical) axioms and rules
>
> Natural deduction and Sequent-calculus : rules only.

In the first case, we say that a theorem of "pure" logic (like e.g. $\forall x \ (x=x)$) is a formula derivable form logical axioms alone.

In the second case, a (logical) theorem has no premises : it needs no non-logical axioms.

Due to the [soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Soundness) of the calculus, every (logical) theorem is *valid* (every theorem of propositional calculus is a tautology).

---

We say that a formula $\varphi$ is a [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) of a set $\Gamma$ of *premises*, in symbols:

> $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$

if and only if

> there is no model $\mathcal {M}$ in which all members of $\Gamma$  are true and $\varphi$ is false.

Due to [(strong) soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Strong_soundness) of first-order logic, every theorem (in the above sense) of first-order arithmetic is a *logical consequence* of (first-order) Peano axioms.

Comment: Can I just clarify that last bit.  Would the axioms (for Peano arithmetic or whatever theory) reside in $\Gamma$?

Comment: @esotechnica - exactly; in the case of f-o arithmetic, $\Gamma$ is the (infinite) set of Peano axioms and $\varphi$ is .e.g. $\forall x \forall y (x+y=y+x)$.