# Using the phrase "Tautology False" to describe something that is always FALSE or OFF

Tags: discrete-mathematics, programming

Programmer here. I sometimes catch myself saying that something is a Tautology False because it always evaluates to FALSE or OFF. I know Tautology means always True in discrete math but I use it to describe something that doesn't change. It's always constant in being False or Null, etc. Am I being illogical.

Comment: I'm not sure "tautology false" is even grammatically correct. If you rephrase it to "tautologically false", *then* we can debate whether that is proper usage.

Comment: Just say "always".

Comment: Some phrases you might see used in logic for something that is always false are "contradictory/a contradiction", "impossible/an impossibility", "absurd/an absurdity", "invalid/an invalidity". Just saying "it's always false" is fine too. You could say "its negation is a tautology" or "it's the negation of a tautology". "Tautologically false" sounds a bit weird to me. Beware the meaning of "tautology" in logic [is subtle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1963508). EG "for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $n$ is of the form $2k$ or $n$ is of the form $2k + 1$" would be a theorem rather than a tautology.

Comment: In logic, we say [Contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction) a proposition that is **always** FALSE. Obviously, being a *tautology* a proposition that is always TRUE, the negation of a tautology is a contradiction.